# Subquery returned more than 1 value - error

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make this query work but I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I saw other question with same problem but I did not understand anyway.

```
SELECT DoctorsVisits.VisitDate,
       (SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total
        FROM DoctorsVisits
        WHERE (DoctorsVisits.PeriodOfVisitId=2)
        GROUP BY DoctorsVisits.VisitDate) AS Manhas
FROM DoctorsVisits;
```

Comment: The reason why is because you have multiple `VisitDate` values per `PeriodOfVisitId` (which is what you're grouping by).  You're doing an unnecessary sub-query here.  What are you trying to get as a result?

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` subquery is returning more than one value.  This is the source of your error.

Comment: You got the answer above. You group by VisitDate, so you get *one* record *per VisitDate*, But you should only select *one* record at all in your subselect. Siyual is also right supposing that you are likely to approach your problem in a wrong way. Please tag your DBMS and tell us what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't simply want a plain group by without sub-query?

```
SELECT DoctorsVisits.VisitDate, count(*) as Manhas
FROM DoctorsVisits
group by DoctorsVisits.VisitDate
```

Or perhaps:

```
SELECT DoctorsVisits.VisitDate,
       sum(case when DoctorsVisits.PeriodOfVisitId=2 then 1 else 0 end) as Manhas
FROM DoctorsVisits
group by DoctorsVisits.VisitDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following.  You're using an unnecessary sub-query for your `COUNT`.

```
SELECT  DoctorsVisits.VisitDate, COUNT(*) As Total 
FROM    DoctorsVisits
WHERE   DoctorsVisits.PeriodOfVisitId=2
GROUP BY DoctorsVisits.VisitDate
```